# how can i get the functionality of fb:chat-invite using facebooks javascript sdk or xfbml

Tags: javascript, facebook, xfbml

From [this forum entry](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=54663) it appears that fb:chat-invite is not a valid xfbml
tag, so to use it one needs to use serverfbml. However testing out

```
<fb:serverfbml>
  <script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:date t="1216170865" format="long_numeric" /> hello again
  </script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

results in

```
<fb:serverfbml> requires the "fbml" attribute.
```

So how can one get the functionality of fb:chat-invite when using xfbml and the javascript
sdk. Is there a way to use fbml with an FB.ui dialog? If so how would that work.

Pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the above example it should read:

```
<fb:serverFbml style="width: 755px;">  
     <script type="text/fbml">
        <fb:fbml>
            <fb:date t="1216170865" format="long_numeric" /> hello again
        </fb:fbml>
    </script>
</fb:serverFbml>
```

For a facebook chat invite try:

```
<fb:serverfbml>
  <script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:chat-invite msg="let's play a game!" condensed="false"/>
  </script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

Comment: It does not work as I noted in my post the error that is generated is <fb:serverfbml> requires the "fbml" attribute. This is because to use xfbml the FB.init calls takes a xfbml: true attribute. The problem is "how does one use <fb:serverFbml> WHEN using xfbml"?

Comment: Testing the above code works in the http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/ which allows you to test XFBML

Comment: In http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/ the chatbox shows up, but it does not show up the friends who are currently logged in and is non-functional. It seems that fb:chat-invite is not currently usable in either iframe or xfbml but only within fbml apps (which facebook is discontinuing)